# Multidimensional keyed array?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a multidimensional keyed array.

How do I declare the array and then push things in to it?

Is this right?

```
var galleryData = new Array();
$("#gallery li.gallery-image-item:not(:first)").each(function() {


    galleryData.push({comment: 'comment', youTube: 'ODOIUOIhd'});

}
```

Thanks

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: That's valid JavaScript code to produce an array of objects; whether or not it produces what you actually want it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Missing the end bracket though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will work.  An alternative syntax is

```
var galleryData = [];
```

Which is nice because yo can then do something like this:

```
var superGalleryData = [[],[],[]]; //creates an array of 3 arrays
```

Another answer suggests using an associative array but it is generally not a good idea:
http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'keyed' array I think you need something like

```
array['key'] = { comment: 'comment', youtube: 'ODD2345UI' };
```

Comment: If they want to do that they want an object, not an array; if you do `array['key']` you're just setting a property on the Array object, you're not adding an element to the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my test for you: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/MtuLc/1/

```
var galleryData = [];
$("#gallery li.gallery-image-item:not(:first)").each(function() {
    galleryData.push({comment: 'comment', youTube: 'ODOIUOIhd'});
});
```

Note that I fixed your missing bracket and changed your `Array` notation. I've also used jQuery *just* to output onto the page.